# Web socket limit incoming data

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket

Hi I am receiving huge chunks of data through amazon web socket. I need to fetch only 30 to fifty data points whose certain array must have a length of greater than 0. Also once i receive 30-50 data points I am closing the connection and using setInterval of 3 seconds to fetch data again. I need to make sure that the next time the data that I fetch must be different from the data fetched before. I am doing this on client side in reactjs because I need to update graphs. How can I limit the data based on condition and also fetch different data after every 3 or 10 seconds.

```
var client = new w3cwebsocket(
    "wss://---------.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev"
  );

  client.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log("Connection Error", e);
  };

  client.onclose = function () {
    console.log("echo-protocol Client Closed");
  };

  client.onmessage = function (e) {
    if (typeof e.data === "string") {
      console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
    }
  };
```

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Along with a description of what your intention is it is important to add as much relevant information, including all code and/or any documentation that you feel is pertinent.